# Create column from array of struct Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm pretty new to data processing.
I have a deeply nested dataset that have this approximately this schema :

```
 |-- col1 : string
 |-- col2 : string
 |-- col3: struct
 |    |-- something : string
 |    |-- elem: array
 |    |    |-- registrationNumber: struct
 |    |    |     |-- registrationNumber : string
 |    |    |     |-- registrationNumberType : string
 |    |    |     |-- registrationCode : int
```

For the array, I will receive something like this. Keep in mind that the length is variable, I might receive no value or 10 or even more

```
[
  {
    registrationNumber : 123456789
    registrationNumberType : VAT
    registrationCode : 1234
  },
  {
    registrationNumber : ABCDERTYU
    registrationNumberType : fiscal1
    registrationCode : 9876
  },
  {
    registrationNumber : 123456789
    registrationNumberType : foo
    registrationCode : 8765
  }
]
```

Is there a way to transform the schema to :

```
 |-- col1 : string
 |-- col2 : string
 |-- col3: struct
 |    |-- something : string
 |    |-- VAT: string
 |    |-- fiscal1: string
```

with `VAT` and `fiscal1` value being the `registrationNumber` value.
I basically need to get a column with the `VAT` and the `fiscal1` value as column

Thanks so much

Edit:

Here is a sample json of `col3`

```
{
        "col3": {
            "somestring": "xxxxxx",
            "registrationNumbers": [
              {
                'registrationNumber' : 'something',
                'registrationNumberType' : 'VAT'
              },
              {
                'registrationNumber' : 'somethingelse',
                'registrationNumberType' : 'fiscal1'
              },
              {
                'registrationNumber' : 'something i dont need',
                'registrationNumberType' : 'fiscal2'
              }
            ]
        }
}
```

and here is what I would like to have :

```
{
        "col3": {
            "somestring": "xxxxxx",
            "VAT" : "something"
            "fiscal1" : "somethingelse"
        }
}
```

Maybe I can, create a dataframe using the array and the primary key, create `VAT` and `fiscal1` columns and select data from the new dataframe to input in the column?
Finally to join the 2 dataframes using the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) function to explode and expand the struct elements of `col3.registrationNumbers` array, then filter only rows with `registrationNumberType` either `VAT` or `fiscal1` and pivot. After pivot, update the struct column `col3`with the pivoted columns:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

exampleJSON = '{"col1":"col1_XX","col2":"col2_XX","col3":{"somestring":"xxxxxx","registrationNumbers":[{"registrationNumber":"something","registrationNumberType":"VAT"},{"registrationNumber":"somethingelse","registrationNumberType":"fiscal1"},{"registrationNumber":"something i dont need","registrationNumberType":"fiscal2"}]}}'
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([exampleJSON]))

df1 = df.selectExpr("*", "inline(col3.registrationNumbers)") \
    .filter(F.col("registrationNumberType").isin(["VAT", "fiscal1"])) \
    .groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3") \
    .pivot("registrationNumberType") \
    .agg(F.first("registrationNumber")) \
    .withColumn("col3", F.struct(F.col("col3.somestring"), F.col("VAT"), F.col("fiscal1"))) \
    .drop("VAT", "fiscal1")

df1.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: struct (nullable = false)
# |    |-- somestring: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- VAT: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- fiscal1: string (nullable = true)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+-------+-------+----------------------------------+
#|col1   |col2   |col3                              |
#+-------+-------+----------------------------------+
#|col1_XX|col2_XX|{xxxxxx, something, somethingelse}|
#+-------+-------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but it doesn't look like it will work for me as i need the column to be the value in the field. I just looked a bit around and it looks like it is more like a pivot.

Comment: @pida Hi! Please post some example data and expected output, it's not clear

Comment: i updated the post with sample data and something i was going to do

Comment: @pida I edited my answer according to your updated question.

Comment: Thanks so much, that looks a lot like it, i'm going to check your solution